# CloudNativePG cluster desired instances Prometheus metric

Tags: prometheus, cloudnative-pg

Is there a Prometheus metric that indicates how many instances is the desired state of a cluster? I couldn't find one. This becomes a problem when trying to create a `PrometheusRule` that identifies a CNPG cluster that has no running instances.

Traditionally, you would have a `StatefulSet` from which you could infer the target replicas, as opposed to the actual ready instances.

In the case of [CNPG](https://cloudnative-pg.io/documentation/current/architecture/) there are only pods, as the operator does not use `Deployment` or `StagefulSet`, but instead managed `Pod`s directly.

And when Pods are offline there remains no data from `PodMonitors` to use in a `PrometheusRule`.